# How to get all pages from API - Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

I have an API that have multiple pages so I need to loop through all of the pages to get eveything. However, I am not sure how to do this properly. I have written the code below but it gives me an error: SyntaxError: 'return' outside function.

```
import requests

def get_json(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response.json() 

def my_range(start, end, step):
    while start <= end:
        yield start
        start += step

for pageNumber in my_range(1, 3, 1):
    return 

data_json = get_json('https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/events/search/?token=MYAPIKEY&expand=venue&location.latitude=55.676097&location.longitude=12.568337&location.within=5km&page='+pageNumber)

eventbrite = data["events"]
```

Comment: It means you have a `return` statement outside a function. After your `for pageNumber in ...` for loop you have a single `return` on its own - what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 1):

There's a design error in the code provided. In the first two def:s you define two functions without problem, but then I take it you're writing the main without declaring

```
def main():
```

and calling main() afterwards. The error results from the "return" in a funny place.

Comment: Yes, that would fix the `SyntaxError` but the code won't work properly. A solution would be to remove the `return` statement and indent the following lines. Still this will result in a `TypeError` when the op tries to concatenate `str + int`, but this can be fixed easily

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the `requests` library I'd take a look at the `params` documentation [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls). This will help you bypass the manual injection you are doing when you call `get_json()`. If you know how many pages you have, you can loop through each page and make a network call for each page - if you have 10 pages, you'll end up making 10 network calls.

This of course assumes that you *have* to paginate each endpoint